# How to batch-cancel tasks in Oxygen Not Included?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

So far I've only discovered one way to cancel any sort of task, be it construction, deconstruction or some service task, and it's to select items one by one and press the corresponding button. But if I want to cancel lots of tasks for a selected area of objects, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a whole dedicated tool for that, hotkey is C (for **C**ancel). It's in the bottom right corner of the screen, and there are filters for what exactly you want to cancel. Same for the deconstruction tool which is right next to it.